# Contains into JSON array PostgreSQL

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I am trying to find specific value in a JSON array placed at PostgreSQL DB. I searched for some solutions (visited all the links when u search smth like "find value in json array postgresql") and tried them but I haven't succeeded, here the last one working example for me:

```
SELECT json_column
FROM table t,
     LATERAL (
         SELECT array_agg(json::text::integer) arr
         FROM json_array_elements(t.json_column -> 'ids') json
         ) subquery;
```

And this solution just prints out my JSON column. I understand the workflow of `json_array_elements` and `array_agg` but `LATERAL` is magic for me. Maybe it is the cause?

The JSON structure I have:

```
[
  {
    "ids": [
      12312,
      123123,
      124124,
      124124124,
      12,
      12234
    ]
  }
]
```

So, I need to understand how to extract values and find the one I need. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the result you are looking for? And which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: postgres:13.1,

expected: column with one row where the searched value is

Comment: You mean the position of a specific value inside the array?

Comment: In your query you only `SELECT json_column`, so basically it prints out the json column, the `LATERAL` query is just without any effect here. What is the criteria to filter the right value from your json data : the position in the json array, the value, ... anything else ?

Comment: @Edouard, the JSON structure that I have posted is saved in DB the way I showed in the post. So, I have a key, called ids, and array of ids. I just need smth like this:

SELECT table.ids WHERE ids.value = 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `json_array_elements` to unpack the json array
- Join each row with unpacked array elems
- Filter by unpacked elem value

```sql
select t.* from my_table t
cross join json_array_elements(json_column->'ids') as j(id)
where j.id::text = '12312';
```

**Update**

As there is an outer array, and only one object in the outer array, this modification seems to be sufficent:

```sql
select t.* from my_table t
cross join json_array_elements(
    json_array_element(json_column,0)->'ids'
) as j(id)
where j.id::text = '12312';
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! But this solution gives me empty output.

Comment: It works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=692b7cc83fd23c757ae872b8218cb2df

Comment: Hmm, I am using PgAdmin, maybe it can't reproduce this

Comment: Oh, I have [{ combination whereas json in your solution starts with {

Comment: And in case [{ of this combination empty output occurs

Comment: Ah, I see - you have another outer array as root. Does the outer array have an arbitrary number of objects (each having "ids" field), and you want to search in any of the objects?

Comment: it seems strange but I have such an odd json column where this structure was applied. It is just as it is. So each column contains one "strange" json as in my example, but with different values inside. Outer array contains only one "ids" field, so I just need to search for the value there.

Comment: Please check updated answer and dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c3cab9916ec2cc458ebd068f834d0c98